# How to discover financial Year based on current datetime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, linq, .net-3.5

I need a financial year based on current or today's datetime.

Suppose if we consider today's date is `10 April 2011`, then i need the outputs as `Financial Year 2012` and for some cases i need to display the same output in short format as `FY12`. Both ways i want to display.

In our requirement financial Year considered is from `April` (*the current year*) to `March` (*following year*).

Based on current datetime...the scenario of output is depends on the current datetime falls in the below said period or duration.

```
From 01April2011 to 31March2012 - Financial Year 2012 or FY2012
From 01April2012 to 31March2013 -  Financial Year 2013 or FY2013
From 01April2013 to 31March2014 -  Financial Year 2014 or FY2014
.
.
.
```

so on....

Another example: If we take today's datetime as 16April2012, then the output is needed as  `Financial Year 2013` and also `FY13`.

Please help how to acheive the same in very short format using LINQ or Regex in C#, .Net3.5

Comment: What has this got to do with LINQ and Regex, won't simple if else work for you ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A couple of Extension methods

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static string ToFinancialYear(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return "Financial Year " + (dateTime.Month >= 4 ? dateTime.Year + 1 : dateTime.Year);
    }

    public static string ToFinancialYearShort(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return "FY" + (dateTime.Month >= 4 ? dateTime.AddYears(1).ToString("yy") : dateTime.ToString("yy"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've done the before by creating a `FinancialYear` class:

```
public class FinancialYear
{
    int yearNumber;
    private static readonly int firstMonthInYear = 4;

    public static FinancialYear Current
    {
        get { return new FinancialYear(DateTime.Today); }
    }

    public FinancialYear(DateTime forDate) 
    {
         if (forDate.Month < firstMonthInYear) {
             yearNumber = forDate.Year + 1;
         }
         else {
             yearNumber = forDate.Year;
         }
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return yearNumber.ToString();
    }
}
```

Other points:

- Have a look at IFormatProvider to see how you can customize formatting (you could provide an overload of ToString that takes a format argument like DateTime does.
- override Equals, and implement IEquitable to provide equality.
- Implement IComparable to give comarisons.
- You could also implement your own == < > >= and <= operators for the class.

Answer (score 1):

Where the financial year is variable (e.g. a company financial year may run July > June rather than follow April > March tax year)

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension method to get the start of the financial year
/// </summary>    
public static DateTime GetStartOfFinancialYear(this DateTime date, int startMonthOfFinancialYear)
{
    if (startMonthOfFinancialYear < 1 || startMonthOfFinancialYear > 12)
        throw new ArgumentException("Must be between 1 and 12","startMonthOfFinancialYear");

    DateTime rtn = new DateTime(date.Year,startMonthOfFinancialYear,1);
    if (date.Month < startMonthOfFinancialYear)
    {
        // Current FY starts last year - e.g. given April to March FY then 1st Feb 2013 FY starts 1st April 20*12*
        rtn = rtn.AddYears(-1);
    }

    return rtn;
}

// Example, Financial Year starts in July
DateTime startFY = DateTime.Now.GetStartOfFinancialYear(7);
DateTime endFY = startFY.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: The endFY in this code is going to be wrong by almost a whole day.  The end of the financial year would be startFY.AddYears(1).AddTicks(-1) to get 23:59:59.9999999... your code is going to give the start of the last day of the financial year not the end of it

Answer (score 1):

To improve on Russ' answer above, I would suggest:

- consolidate 2 extension methods into 1 - common addition logic
- add arguments for Short/Long and the month (some need Oct instead of April)
- add default values
- leave out the "Financial Year" because some might use "Fiscal Year"

```
public static string ToFYString(this DateTime dateTime, bool longFlag = false, int monthLimit = 3)
{
   var format = longFlag ? "yyyy" : "yy";
   return (dateTime.Month > monthLimit ? dateTime.AddYears(1).ToString(format) : dateTime.ToString(format));
}
```

1. if april is your new FY, and you want short, use `.ToFYString()`
2. if october is your new FY and you want short use `.ToFYString(monthLimit: 9)`
3. if april is your new FY, and you want long, use `.ToFYString(true)`
4. if october is your new FY, and you want long, use `.ToFYString(true, 9)`

Answer (score 1):

Try the bellow code to get the Financial year or the period value.

```
public int GetFinancialYear(DateTime date)
{
    return date.Month > 6 ? date.Year + 1 : date.Year;
}

public int GetFinancialPeriod(DateTime date)
{
    return date.Month > 6 ? date.Month - 6 : date.Month + 6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would need LINQ but won't something like this suffice

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
if(today.Month <= 3)
       make this string "Financial Year " + today.ToString("yy")); // OR yyyy for 2013
else 
       "Financial Year " + today.AddYears(1).ToString("yy"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FinancialYear
{
    public YearRepresentation ResolveFinancialYear(DateTime currentDate)
    {
        YearRepresentation financialYear = new YearRepresentation();
        int year = (currentDate.Month >= 4) ? currentDate.AddYears(1).Year : currentDate.Year;
        financialYear.SetYear(year);

        return financialYear;
    }
}

public class YearRepresentation
{
    public string LongYear { get; set; }

    public string ShortYear { get; set; }

    public void SetYear(int year)
    {
        this.LongYear = "Financial Year " + year;
        this.ShortYear = "FY " + year;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This an example for finding current financial year.

```
        string FinYear=null;

        if (DateTime.Today.Month > 3)
        {

            FinYear = "1/4/" + DateTime.Today.Year;
        }

        else
        {
            FinYear = "1/4/" + (DateTime.Today.Year - 1);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here used Valued Tuple (Finacial year start from July so, I used 7.
If you want

> Month-year to Month-year

the format then just need to use month and Year Property of start date and End Date.

```
public  static (DateTime, DateTime) GetCurrentFinacialYearDateRange()
    {
        if(DateTime.Now.Month >= 7)
        {
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 7, 1); // 1st July this year
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year + 1, 7, 1).AddDays(-1); // Last day in June next year
            return (startDate, endDate);
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year-1, 7, 1); // 1st July this year
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 7, 1).AddDays(-1); // Last day in June next year
            return (startDate, endDate);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?